# My Windows 10 guest OS emulated with qemu / kvm is not able to boot itself anymore?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

Houston,I have a problem trying to boot again Windows 10 guest emulated with qemu and kvm on Linux ubuntu. This problem arised when I have installed Windows server 2019 on the 2 ssd disk (named disk1 mbr / samsung 860 EVO).Below you can see how my disks are organized :

[image]

you can see that sda (CT500) is the disk where I run windows 10 pro (partition scheme = GPT / EFI) and the sdb is the disk where I have installed windows server 2019 (partition scheme = MBR). The other disks are not bootable. Below you can see how the disks are seen by the BIOS :

[image]

at the first place there is SDA,but when I try to boot the PC clicking over the first voice,it does not boot. To boot it I should click on the 10 position,where is the WINDOWS BOOT MANAGER HIDDEN EFI partition that u see on picture 1. I tried to move this hidden partition from position 10 to 1 with easyuefi,but when I have rebooted the PC,I saw no changes. Instead,below,you can see how virt-manager sees my disks :

[image]
[image]
[image]

and below you can see how I have configued the boot order of the first disk when it worked :

[image]

Below is the message that I see when windows 10 tries to boot :

**

```
BdsDxe: loading Boot0002 "Windows Boot manager" from HD(3,GPT,0F97C461-623E-4123-8C8B-6931983472CD,0x13A000,0x31800)/\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
BdsDxe: starting Boot0002 "Windows Boot manager" from HD(3,GPT,0F97C461-623E-4123-8C8B-6931983472CD,0x13A000,0x31800)/\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
```

**

Basically Windows always goes in recovery mode.

Do u understand what's wrong ? How can I fix it ? I would like to understand what are the correct value to boot again Windows 10 (boot order and / or unit number ? or what ?)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: CT500MX500SSD4
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A1F38312-1D0A-4947-A0C6-C7A7A4EB7266

Dispositivo Start Fine Settori Size Tipo
/dev/sda1 34 262177 262144 128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2 264192 1286143 1021952 499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3 1286144 1488895 202752 99M EFI System
/dev/sda4 1488896 975591423 974102528 464,5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5 975591424 976773119 1181696 577M Windows recovery environment

30: IDE 100.0: 10600 Disk
[Created at block.245]
Unique ID: 3OOL.9WR0epkx4QA
Parent ID: abAj.mTn4ZiMB_e3
SysFS ID: /class/block/sda
SysFS BusID: 1:0:0:0
SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0
Hardware Class: disk
Model: "CT500MX500SSD4"
Device: "CT500MX500SSD4"
Revision: "023"
Serial ID: "1924E20B2AE5"
Driver: "ahci", "sd"
Driver Modules: "ahci"
Device File: /dev/sda
Device Files: /dev/sda, /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x500a0751e20b2ae5, /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:17.0-ata-2, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-CT500MX500SSD4_1924E20B2AE5
Device Number: block 8:0-8:15
Geometry (Logical): CHS 60801/255/63
Size: 976773168 sectors a 512 bytes
Capacity: 465 GB (500107862016 bytes)
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
Attached to: #2 (SATA controller)
```

I would like that Windows 10 boot again without reinstalling Windows 10 !!!!

Comment: Combining dual boot and virtual machines adds more complexity than is useful. It is best avoided.

Comment: yes,but now I need to fix this.

Comment: in the title you say it can't "boot itself *anymore*" ... that implies that it did at one stage?